# Discovering which PCMCIA Wifi card can work on OS X Leopard

Tags: wifi, leopard, driver

I've got an old PowerBook G4. I've installed Mac OS X Leopard on it. Now, i want to buy a PCMCIA wifi card for surfing internet. But I can't understand, which cards are compatible and which not. Information in internet is very old, and I found information only about OS X 10.4. Also, I've read, that all cards,based on broadcom chipset are compatible. For example, does Linksys WPC54G works with my computer?

Answer (score 2):

There is a list of such cards on [Low End Mac up to 10.4](http://lowendmac.com/macdan/md09/mac-wifi-pc-card.htm)

But I believe better way would be just to go to ebay for [native Airport Extreme](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=AirPort%20Extreme%20powerbook&_sacat=0&_odkw=AirPort%20Extreme&gbr=1&_fcid=209&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_clu=2) if your particular model is aluminum one.

If it is [Titanium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerBook_G4#Titanium_PowerBook_G4) then CardBus is the way to go since original Airport 802.11b cards are rare, pricier and don't support WPA2.

P.S. And I wouldn't recommend 10.5 on Titanium Powerbook